# Facing Issue with sending axios.post request to backend server, through Formik within React, MaterialUI

Tags: reactjs, axios, material-ui, formik

I am trying to use Formik through useFormik hook in a MaterialUI Project. The "onSubmit" functionality seems to work fine basis console log checks but the POST request doesnt seem to go through as no new entry gets updated at the database - MySQL. The backend API endPoint seems fine as per the postman responses. Please help in identifying the issue

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

import { Box, Card, Container, Grid, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import PageTitle from '../pageTitle/PageTitle';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import ArrowBackIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowBack';
import { FormControl } from '@mui/material';
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import * as yup from 'yup';
import axios from 'axios';
// import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const validationSchema = yup.object({
    agencyName: yup
        .string()
        .min(8, 'Must be at least 8 characters')
        .max(20, 'Must be less  than 20 characters')
        .required('Username is required')
        .matches(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, 'Cannot contain special characters or spaces'),
    phoneNumber: yup.string().required('Required'),
    // .matches(/^[0-9]*$/, 'Phone number is not valid')
    email: yup
        .string('Enter your email')
        .email('Enter a valid email')
        .required('Email is required'),

    streetAddress: yup.string().required('Required'),
    zipCode: yup.string().required('Required'),
    state: yup.string().required('Required'),
    country: yup.string().required('Required'),
});

const AddHRAgency = () => {
    // const navigate = Navigate();

    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            name: '',
            phone: '',
            email: '',
            unit_street_address: '',
            city_address: '',
            zip_code: '',
            state: '',
            country: '',
        },

        // validationSchema: validationSchema,

        onSubmit: async (values, props) => {
            console.log('The Process Starts');

            try {
                console.log('step1');

                const userVal = JSON.stringify(values, null, 2);
                console.log(userVal);
                await axios.post('http://localhost:8800/AddHRAgencies', userVal, {
                    'content-type': 'application/json',
                });
                console.log('step3');
                props.resetForm();
                props.setSubmitting(false);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(`Error OCCURRED:: ${error}`);
            }
            console.log('The Process Ends');
        },
    });

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Box
                sx={{
                    margin: '1rem',
                    padding: '1rem',
                    background:
                        'linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(194,203,217,1) 76%)',
                }}
            >
                <Paper
                    sx={{
                        width: '100%',
                        display: 'flex',
                        flexDirection: 'column',
                        justifyContent: 'space-around',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        height: '100%',
                        background:
                            'linear-gradient(4deg, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(214,221,232,1) 81%)',
                    }}
                    variant='outlined'
                >
                    <Box
                        sx={{
                            display: 'flex',
                            alignItems: 'space-evenly',
                            justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
                            flexWrap: 'wrap',
                            gap: '1.5rem',
                            marginTop: '1rem',
                            // position: 'relative',
                        }}
                    >
                        <PageTitle>
                            <Typography variant='h3' sx={{}}>
                                Add a New HR Agency Record
                            </Typography>
                        </PageTitle>

                        <form
                            // component='form'
                            onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}
                            sx={{
                                // '& .MuiTextField-root': { m: 1, width: '25ch' },
                                margin: '1rem 0',
                                width: '80%',
                            }}
                        >
                            {/* <FormControl
                                sx={{
                                    width: '100%',
                                    display: 'flex',
                                    justifyContent: 'center',
                                    alignItems: 'center',
                                }}
                            > */}
                            <Grid container spacing={2}>
                                <Grid item xs={12}>
                                    <TextField
                                        required
                                        id='outlined-basic'
                                        label='Name'
                                        variant='outlined'
                                        margin='normal'
                                        fullWidth
                                        type='text'
                                        name='name'
                                        value={formik.values.name}
                                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                        error={formik.touched.name && Boolean(formik.errors.name)}
                                        helperText={formik.touched.name && formik.errors.name}
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item xs={12}>
                                    <TextField
                                        required
                                        id='outlined-basic'
                                        label='Agency Phone'
                                        variant='outlined'
                                        margin='normal'
                                        fullWidth
                                        type='text'
                                        name='phone'
                                        value={formik.values.phone}
                                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                        error={formik.touched.phone && Boolean(formik.errors.phone)}
                                        helperText={formik.touched.phone && formik.errors.phone}
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item xs={12}>
                                    <TextField
                                        required
                                        id='outlined-basic'
                                        label='Agency Email'
                                        variant='outlined'
                                        margin='normal'
                                        fullWidth
                                        type='email'
                                        name='email'
                                        value={formik.values.email}
                                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                        error={formik.touched.email && Boolean(formik.errors.email)}
                                        helperText={formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email}
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item xs={12}>
                                    <TextField
                                        id='outlined-basic'
                                        label='Unit Address'
                                        variant='outlined'
                                        margin='normal'
                                        fullWidth
                                        required
                                        type='text'
                                        name='unit_street_address'
                                        value={formik.values.unit_street_address}
                                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                        error={
                                            formik.touched.unit_street_address &&
                                            Boolean(formik.errors.unit_street_address)
                                        }
                                        helperText={
                                            formik.touched.unit_street_address &&
                                            formik.errors.unit_street_address
                                        }
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item xs={12}>
                                    <TextField
                                        id='outlined-basic'
                                        label='Street Address'
                                        variant='outlined'
                                        margin='normal'
                                        fullWidth
                                        required
                                        type='text'
                                        name='city_address'
                                        value={formik.values.city_address}
                                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                        error={
                                            formik.touched.city_address &&
                                            Boolean(formik.errors.city_address)
                                        }
                                        helperText={
                                            formik.touched.city_address && formik.errors.city_address
                                        }
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item xs={12}>
                                    <TextField
                                        required
                                        id='outlined-basic'
                                        label='Zip code'
                                        variant='outlined'
                                        margin='normal'
                                        fullWidth
                                        type='text'
                                        name='zip_code'
                                        value={formik.values.zip_code}
                                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                        error={
                                            formik.touched.zip_code && Boolean(formik.errors.zip_code)
                                        }
                                        helperText={
                                            formik.touched.zip_code && formik.errors.zip_code
                                        }
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item xs={12}>
                                    <TextField
                                        id='outlined-basic'
                                        label='State'
                                        variant='outlined'
                                        margin='normal'
                                        fullWidth
                                        required
                                        type='text'
                                        name='state'
                                        value={formik.values.state}
                                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                        error={formik.touched.state && Boolean(formik.errors.state)}
                                        helperText={formik.touched.state && formik.errors.state}
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item xs={12}>
                                    <TextField
                                        id='outlined-basic'
                                        label='Country'
                                        variant='outlined'
                                        margin='normal'
                                        fullWidth
                                        required
                                        type='text'
                                        name='country'
                                        value={formik.values.country}
                                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                        error={
                                            formik.touched.country && Boolean(formik.errors.country)
                                        }
                                        helperText={formik.touched.country && formik.errors.country}
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>

                            <Button
                                sx={{
                                    marginTop: '2rem;',
                                    width: '25%',
                                    display: 'flex',
                                    justifyContent: 'center',
                                    alignItems: 'center',
                                }}
                                variant='contained'
                                type='submit'
                            >
                                Submit
                            </Button>
                            {/* </FormControl> */}
                        </form>
                        {/* </form> */}
                        <Button
                            variant='contained'
                            component={NavLink}
                            to='/hragencies'
                            sx={{
                                // marginTop: '2rem;',
                                width: '20%',
                                minWidth: '180px',
                                display: 'flex',
                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                alignItems: 'center',
                                padding: '0.5rem 1.5rem',
                                marginBottom: '1.5rem',
                            }}
                        >
                            <ArrowBackIcon sx={{ marginRight: '1rem' }} /> HR Agency
                        </Button>
                    </Box>
                </Paper>
            </Box>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default AddHRAgency;
```

Here is a snapshot of Console Log for ref
[Console.Log Image - Axios/Formik issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr7Td.png)

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out , Youssouf. I've added a pic for reference

Comment: No error! Console log outputs correctly. snapshot attached for ref